# Automate download in web using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a script that will login to a site, and then it will click a link and then it needs to export the data to excel file.

The script already have a login to the site 
It is lacking on the download part

```
with requests.Session() as s:
  url="https://website"
  r=s.get(url,headers=headers)
  soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
  login_data['grpstub']=soup.find('input' , attrs={'name':'grpstub'})['value']
  login_data['__VIEWSTATE']=soup.find('input' , attrs={'name':'__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
  login_data['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']=soup.find('input' , attrs={'name':'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'})['value']
  login_data['__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED']=soup.find('input' , attrs={'name':'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'})['value']
  login_data['__EVENTVALIDATION']=soup.find('input' , attrs={'name':'__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']
  r = s.post(url,data=login_data,headers=headers)
  print(r.content)
```

I need to have a script that will do the below export to excel

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duVj8.png)

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup is used to extracts/parse html and xml.

If you want to automate actions (click buttons/ input forms etc.) on a web page you should use something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

That way you can find an element in the page structure (selenium has a lot of builtin selectors) and issue an value (form input) or event (click) etc.